# How to convert Unicode Hex Characters to Latin-1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex, discord.js

I'm using **rae-api** to get the definition of the words in their dictionary. The problem is for example: I search for the definition of the word `hola`, it returns `como salutaci&#xF3;n familiar.`. I want to get the value of `&#xF3;` in Latin-1 characters: `ó`, therefore, the result would be `como salutación familiar.` 
`getHex` function removes `&#;` and returns `xF3` to the text. However, i want to convert all Unicode Hex characters to Latin-1.

I have tested a lot of answers in similar problems, but none of they works for me (example: `decodeURIComponent` or using Hex to utf8 libraries). I'm using **Discord.js**.

> `userInput` is the word to search for

```
const { RAE } = require("rae-api");
const rae = new RAE();
        
//-----------------  RAE  -------------------------

    
function getHex(text) {
   text = text.replace(/&#(.*?);/g, function (a, b) {
        //Get the Latin-1 value of b and return it to the text
        return b;
   })

   return text;
}

rae.searchWord(`${userInput}`).then(r => {
    let wordID = r.getRes()[0].getId();

rae.fetchWord(wordID).then(word => {
    let defs = word.getDefinitions();
    let definition = defs[0].getDefinition();
        
    return message.channel.send(`La definición de ${userInput} es: ${getHex(definition)}`);
})
    
}).catch(e => { return message.channel.send("No se encontró esa palabra!")})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = 'F3';
var decimalValue = parseInt(input, 16); // Base 16 or hexadecimal
var character = String.fromCharCode(decimalValue);
console.log('Input:', input);
console.log('Decimal value:', decimalValue);
console.log('Character representation:', character);
```